# AWS AccessDenied when calling the UploadServerCertificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, openssl, amazon-iam

I ran into a problem with AWS instance when I was trying to import self signed SSL certificate to IAM console following this tutorial -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-ssl.html

Basically tutorial is made to self sign a certificate and upload it to IAM user to have HTTPS application for testing purposes.

I SSH to my instance and ran all those commands, but in the end when I need to import it I get the error that my account is not authorized...

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the
> UploadServerCertificate operation: User:
> arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role/xxxxxxx
> is not authorized to perform: iam:UploadServerCertificate on resource:
> arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:server-certificate/elastic-beanstalk-x509

I'm logged in as a ec2-user into the instance because I didn't find a way to log in with any other user...
I tried running command as sudo and nothing changes. On a similar post I have seen that I need to create a specific IAM user to which I need to append specific group policy to have "IAMFullAccess" policy. But I don't understand how can I specify that I want to run this command as this user since I am logged in as ec2-user on SSH...

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some reading: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html

- Create an IAM role with Upload permission
- Add a trust policy to the role that it will allow it to be assumed by your EC2 instance
- Attach the role to the EC2 instance

From your error it seems that you are using Elastic Beanstalk. This means that you already have a role that is assumed by your EC2. Find this role (xxxxx in the error message) and add the appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have managed to add the certificate to the instance...

> aws iam list-server-certificates   {
> "ServerCertificateMetadataList": [
> {
> "ServerCertificateId": "id",
> "ServerCertificateName": "elastic-beanstalk-x509",
> "Expiration": "2022-10-21T13:07:11Z",
> "Path": "/",
> "Arn": "arn",
> "UploadDate": "2021-10-21T13:42:39Z"
> }
> ] }

I also added Listener and proces on "Modify Application Load Balancer" but the site is still not responding to HTTPS requests... Any idea?

Comment: Hi, thanks for providing additional info and showing you are doing your own research. However an answer to the original question is not the proper way of doing so, instead please edit the question and add the update there, for example under a title *EDIT*. Answers are reserved for solutions to the problem, not replies as in a covnersation or on a forum.